# Can't include TinyXML in C++/CLI project

Tags: c++-cli, tinyxml

I have a C++/CLI project, and I want to include TinyXML.
I downloaded the library, added it as a a new project to my solution and added a reference from my project to the library.

In my code I have

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "tinyxml.h"
```

When i compile i get 70 linking errors. I tried to comment #define TIXML_SAFE in tinyxml.h ( saw that on google ) , but doesnt work.

Thanks, Dave

Comment: Why would you want to use TinyXML in C++/CLI program? What's wrong with #using <System.Xml.dll> ?

Comment: well, very good point. actually i have a part of my project using c++ / cli and other part i keep it clean with c++ only stuff. ( no managed stuff). and actually i need to write xml from that layer...yeah i hate that homework.

Comment: @Dave : A linker error means the compiler sees the header files fine but the linker can't find the .lib files. Did you add the appropriate .lib files to your project settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it, i included tinyxml in a subfolder of my current project, instead of adding it in its own  project. I also used tinyXMLSTL. Thanks.