# Linker Error when attempting to use binary external library

Tags: visual-c++

I am new to C++, having recently taken a class to introduce me to the language, so I understand the basics of the syntax, but there was no discussion of how to use external libraries and connect them to our code.

I am trying to use the CLP COIN library for solving linear programs from...
http://www.coin-or.org/Clp/userguide/clpuserguide.html#id4766717

From what I read there, it suggested to use the precompiled binary libraries rather than download the source, since I am on Windows 7 platform, as they suggested recompiling on Windows can sometimes introduce problems.

I am simply trying to get the equivalent of Hello World working.  Here is the sample code they provided to test with...

```
* Copyright (C) 2004, International Business Machines Corporation 
   and others.  All Rights Reserved.

   This sample program is designed to illustrate programming 
   techniques using CoinLP, has not been thoroughly tested
   and comes without any warranty whatsoever.

   You may copy, modify and distribute this sample program without 
   any restrictions whatsoever and without any payment to anyone.
*/

/* This shows how to provide a simple picture of a matrix.
   The default matrix will print Hello World
*/

#include "ClpSimplex.hpp"

int main (int argc, const char *argv[])
{
  ClpSimplex  model;
  int status;
  // Keep names
  if (argc<2) {
    status=model.readMps("hello.mps",true);
  } else {
    status=model.readMps(argv[1],true);
  }
  if (status)
    exit(10);

  int numberColumns = model.numberColumns();
  int numberRows = model.numberRows();

  if (numberColumns>80||numberRows>80) {
    printf("model too large\n");
    exit(11);
  }
  printf("This prints x wherever a non-zero elemnt exists in matrix\n\n\n");

  char x[81];

  int iRow;
  // get row copy
  CoinPackedMatrix rowCopy = *model.matrix();
  rowCopy.reverseOrdering();
  const int * column = rowCopy.getIndices();
  const int * rowLength = rowCopy.getVectorLengths();
  const CoinBigIndex * rowStart = rowCopy.getVectorStarts();

  x[numberColumns]='\0';
  for (iRow=0;iRow<numberRows;iRow++) {
    memset(x,' ',numberColumns);
    for (int k=rowStart[iRow];k<rowStart[iRow]+rowLength[iRow];k++) {
      int iColumn = column[k];
      x[iColumn]='x';
    }
    printf("%s\n",x);
  }
  printf("\n\n");
  return 0;
}
```

I have associated the Include and Lib directories with my project in Visual Studio, but when I attempt to build, get a number of linker errors such as:

```
Simplex(void)" (??1ClpSimplex@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
1>hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall CoinPackedMatrix::~CoinPackedMatrix(void)" (??1CoinPackedMatrix@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
1>hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall CoinPackedMatrix::reverseOrdering(void)" (?reverseOrdering@CoinPackedMatrix@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function _main
1>hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall CoinPackedMatrix::CoinPackedMatrix(class CoinPackedMatrix const &)" (??0CoinPackedMatrix@@QAE@ABV0@@Z) referenced in function _main
1>hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall ClpSimplex::readMps(char const *,bool,bool)" (?readMps@ClpSimplex@@QAEHPBD_N1@Z) referenced in function _main
1>hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall ClpSimplex::ClpSimplex(bool)" (??0ClpSimplex@@QAE@_N@Z) referenced in function _main
```

As a newbie, I am clueless as to how to approach resolving this issue, since my course only covered debugging associated with code syntax, not linker issues.

Any tips or links to other threads would be of great help.  I have been Googling all day, but am at a loss...

Comment: Had a similar problem with c++ cli and external tiny xml lib, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999678/cant-include-tinyxml-in-c-cli-project

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you did to associate the Lib directories with the project, but you'll need to make sure that these are done (the first is often overlooked):

- You need to add the library filename to the Project's "Linker/Input/Additional Dependencies" property.
- You might also need to place the location of the library in the Project's "Linker/General/Additional Library Directories" property - depending on if you give the proper path or just the filename ion the above property.  This is probably what you already did.

---

Update:

In the dumpbin output you posted, you'll see the following entry:

```
4C3 0000AE4A SECT98 notype () External | ?readMps@ClpSimplex@@QEAAHPEBD_N 1@Z (public: int __cdecl ClpSimplex::readMps(char const *,bool,bool))
```

In the error message, you'll see this:

```
1>hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall ClpSimplex::readMps(char const *,bool,bool)" (?readMps@ClpSimplex@@QAEHPBD_N1@Z) referenced in function _main
```

Compare the de-mangled names from the two messages:

```
public: int __cdecl ClpSimplex::readMps(char const *,bool,bool)     // what's in the .lib
public: int __thiscall ClpSimplex::readMps(char const *,bool,bool)  // what hello.obj is asking for
```

You'll see that the two calling conventions are different. Looking on the coin-or.org website, it looks like the library was built with VC 2005. For Microsoft compilers, the libraries cannot always be used with different compiler versions.  I suggest that you use VC 2005 if you want to use this pre-built library (you should still be able to get the free Express version here: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=57034).

FWIW, I tried compiling the example with several MS compilers and got the following results (build only - the program complains about some file being missing when I try to run it:

- worked: VC 2005 and VC 2008
- failed: VC 6 and VC2010

Comment: Yes, I did each of those steps, along with changing C++/Addl Include Directories so it could find the header.  Even with those 3 config settings, I still get the errors shown.

Comment: Let me know if you have any other suggestions (if you are still following this thread).  Thanks...

Comment: @JoshDailey: try opening a VS command window and running `dumpbin /symbols coin-lib-name.lib | find "readMps"` and post the results (of course, replace `coin-lib-name.lib` with the actual filename of the library - including the path if necessary).  I'd like to see how the name in the library compares to the name in the error message above.

Comment: How do you put a friggin line break in this thing?!?

Comment: There are 2 lib files in question.  The first libClp.lib produces these results (Heaven knows how anyone is supposed to read this without line breaks):

Comment: c:\clp\lib>dumpbin /symbols libClp.lib | find "readMps"
4C3 0000AE4A SECT98 notype ()    External     | ?readMps@ClpSimplex@@QEAAHPEBD_N
1@Z (public: int __cdecl ClpSimplex::readMps(char const *,bool,bool))
4C4 00000000 UNDEF  notype ()    External     | ?readMps@ClpModel@@QEAAHPEBD_N1@
Z (public: int __cdecl ClpModel::readMps(char const *,bool,bool))
4C5 00000ABC SECT9A notype       Static       | $unwind$?readMps@ClpSimplex@@QEA
AHPEBD_N1@Z
4C6 0000039C SECT9B notype       Static       | $pdata$?readMps@ClpSimplex@@QEAA
HPEBD_N1@Z

Comment: 743 0000B02A SECT8D notype ()    External     | ?readMps@ClpModel@@QEAAHPEBD_N1@
Z (public: int __cdecl ClpModel::readMps(char const *,bool,bool))
74B 00000000 UNDEF  notype ()    External     | ?readMps@CoinMpsIO@@QEAAHPEBD0@Z
 (public: int __cdecl CoinMpsIO::readMps(char const *,char const *))
771 00000F58 SECT8F notype       Static       | $unwind$?readMps@ClpModel@@QEAAH
PEBD_N1@Z
772 00000AC0 SECT8E notype       Static       | FI_?readMps@ClpModel@@QEAAHPEBD_
N1@Z
773 000004BC SECT90 notype       Static       | $pdata$?readMps@ClpModel@@QEAAHP
EBD_N1@Z

Comment: 796 000011C0 SECT8F notype       Static       | IP2St_?readMps@ClpModel@@QEAAHPE
BD_N1@Z
2C3 00001CB8 SECT83 notype ()    External     | ?readMps@ClpInterior@@QEAAHPEBD_
N1@Z (public: int __cdecl ClpInterior::readMps(char const *,bool,bool))
2C4 00000000 UNDEF  notype ()    External     | ?readMps@ClpModel@@QEAAHPEBD_N1@
Z (public: int __cdecl ClpModel::readMps(char const *,bool,bool))
2C5 000001B8 SECT84 notype       Static       | $unwind$?readMps@ClpInterior@@QE
AAHPEBD_N1@Z

Comment: 2C6 000000F0 SECT85 notype       Static       | $pdata$?readMps@ClpInterior@@QEA
AHPEBD_N1@Z
047 00000238 SECT8  notype ()    External     | Clp_readMps
048 00000000 UNDEF  notype ()    External     | ?readMps@ClpSimplex@@QEAAHPEBD_N
1@Z (public: int __cdecl ClpSimplex::readMps(char const *,bool,bool))
049 00000094 SECT9  notype       Static       | $unwind$Clp_readMps
04A 00000054 SECTA  notype       Static       | $pdata$Clp_readMps

Comment: c:\clp\lib>dumpbin /symbols libCoinUtils.lib | find "readMps"
0FE 00001E50 SECT5  notype ()    External     | ?readMps@CoinMpsIO@@QEAAHPEBD0@Z
 (public: int __cdecl CoinMpsIO::readMps(char const *,char const *))
105 000059F6 SECT5  notype ()    External     | ?readMps@CoinMpsIO@@QEAAHXZ (pub
lic: int __cdecl CoinMpsIO::readMps(void))
107 000003BC SECT6  notype       Static       | $unwind$?readMps@CoinMpsIO@@QEAA
HPEBD0@Z
108 00000190 SECT8  notype       Static       | FI_?readMps@CoinMpsIO@@QEAAHPEBD
0@Z

Comment: 109 00000240 SECT7  notype       Static       | $pdata$?readMps@CoinMpsIO@@QEAAH
PEBD0@Z
10C 000003F8 SECT6  notype       Static       | IP2St_?readMps@CoinMpsIO@@QEAAHP
EBD0@Z
194 00005A92 SECT5  notype ()    External     | ?readMps@CoinMpsIO@@QEAAHAEAHAEA
PEAPEAVCoinSet@@@Z (public: int __cdecl CoinMpsIO::readMps(int &,class CoinSet *
 * &))
195 0000086C SECT6  notype       Static       | $unwind$?readMps@CoinMpsIO@@QEAA
HXZ

Comment: 196 000003F0 SECT7  notype       Static       | $pdata$?readMps@CoinMpsIO@@QEAAH
XZ
197 00000874 SECT6  notype       Static       | $unwind$?readMps@CoinMpsIO@@QEAA
HXZ$B3_B8
198 000003FC SECT7  notype       Static       | $pdata$?readMps@CoinMpsIO@@QEAAH
XZ$B3_B8
199 00000884 SECT6  notype       Static       | $unwind$?readMps@CoinMpsIO@@QEAA
HXZ$B9_B11
19A 00000408 SECT7  notype       Static       | $pdata$?readMps@CoinMpsIO@@QEAAH
XZ$B9_B11

Comment: 1C0 0000088C SECT6  notype       Static       | $unwind$?readMps@CoinMpsIO@@QEAA
HAEAHAEAPEAPEAVCoinSet@@@Z
1C1 00000570 SECT8  notype       Static       | FI_?readMps@CoinMpsIO@@QEAAHAEAH
AEAPEAPEAVCoinSet@@@Z
1C2 00000414 SECT7  notype       Static       | $pdata$?readMps@CoinMpsIO@@QEAAH
AEAHAEAPEAPEAVCoinSet@@@Z
1DD 00000A48 SECT6  notype       Static       | IP2St_?readMps@CoinMpsIO@@QEAAHA
EAHAEAPEAPEAVCoinSet@@@Z

Comment: 226 0000D5DC SECT5  notype ()    External     | ?readMps@CoinMpsIO@@QEAAHPEBD0AE
AHAEAPEAPEAVCoinSet@@@Z (public: int __cdecl CoinMpsIO::readMps(char const *,cha
r const *,int &,class CoinSet * * &))
228 00000C40 SECT6  notype       Static       | $unwind$?readMps@CoinMpsIO@@QEAA
HPEBD0AEAHAEAPEAPEAVCoinSet@@@Z
229 00000860 SECT8  notype       Static       | FI_?readMps@CoinMpsIO@@QEAAHPEBD
0AEAHAEAPEAPEAVCoinSet@@@Z
22A 00000528 SECT7  notype       Static       | $pdata$?readMps@CoinMpsIO@@QEAAH
PEBD0AEAHAEAPEAPEAVCoinSet@@@Z

Comment: 22D 00000C6C SECT6  notype       Static       | IP2St_?readMps@CoinMpsIO@@QEAAHP
EBD0AEAHAEAPEAPEAVCoinSet@@@Z
64F 00000000 UNDEF  notype ()    External     | ?readMps@CoinMpsIO@@QEAAHPEBD0@Z
 (public: int __cdecl CoinMpsIO::readMps(char const *,char const *))

Comment: @Josh: I think the key item is in the first `dumpbin` snippet you posted.  Please see the update in my answer.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply!!  You really went overboard in your response.  I got pulled away from this for a few weeks so am just circling back now.  So apologies for my delayed thanks.  I understand your description, but moving forward, can you suggest any URLs that would help me understand how to debug linker errors on my own in future?  In other words, you have helped me to address this problem, but do you have any suggestions about how I can better understand this so I can solve my own problems moving forward?  How did you know how to diagnose this issue?

Comment: @Josh: all you have to do is realize that the fundamental thing a linker is doing is matching names.  So if the linker is complaining that it can't find a reference, then there are pretty much three causes: 1) you're missing a library or object file, 2) the names are off (usually due to a function signature difference), or 3) the function/variable it's looking for didn't get built into the libraries/object files.  The only less-than-obvious tricks I've used here are extracting useful names from the mangled names in the linker errors, and dumping the names in the libraries.

Comment: The additional thing that happened here is the mismatch of compiler versions. You have to keep in mind that MSVC typically doesn't support mixing object files from one compiler version being linked with object files from a different compiler version. That fact may not be made obvious in the MSDN docs unless you read them pretty carefully. That's the reason that libraries such as Boost have to supply a slew of .lib files to support the history of MSVC versions. DLLs may be able to avoid that problem as long as the DLL exports don't need to use C++ external names.